# Proof by Contradiction with Definition of odd Issue with Z domain

Tags: algebra-precalculus, discrete-mathematics, formal-proofs

> I am trying to prove that if $x$ is even, then $x^2 + 4x + 2$ even.

When completing a proof by contradiction I reach this point where I need to use a fraction to get it in the form of the odd definition... is this legal for a domain of $\mathbb{Z}$?
\begin{align}
x^2 + 4x + 2 
&= 32k^3 + 48k^2 + 24k + 6 \\
\implies\quad
x^2 + 4x + 2 
&= 2\bigl(16k^3 + 24k^2 + 12k + \tfrac{5}{2}\bigr) + 1
\end{align}
Let $d = 16k^3 + 24k^2 + 12k + \tfrac{5}{2}$ for some $d$ in ______? I know the standard and answer is $\mathbb{Z}$, but it obviously won't work and I am stuck.  Thanks for any advice.

Comment: I am very confused as to what you are trying to do here. If $x\in \Bbb Z$ is even, then $\exists k\in\Bbb Z$ such that $x=2k$. Then
$$x^2+4x+2 = (2k)^2+4(2k)+2 \\ =4k^2+8k+2 \\ =2(2k^2+4k+1)$$
Which must be even, as it is of the form $2\cdot \text{something}$.

Comment: Thank you!  I completely missed the direct proof

Comment: No doubt it can be done by contradiction, but where did $32k^3+48k^2+24k+6$ come from?